# A linear system of two equation with four variables

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I’ve been stuck with this question for hours now.
We have a linear system of

> 3a - 9b + 2c -d = 4 and
> a -3b +c + 2d = -1

I put this in a matrix and reduced it as much as possible, but I can’t seem to get further. All i know that at my first attempt I was able to get c = -14 and d=1 but out of frustration I deleted that and it turned out to be the right answer. I don’t know how to get there again and do the rest, any help?

Comment: what do you have to do exactly? For that system you'll have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I have to solve for every variable @Schach21

Comment: Do you need to find all solutions or just one?

Comment: It says to find all solutions @Schach21

Comment: I also know that a = 5, b=-2, c=-14 and d=1, cause those numbers seem to make 4 out of the first equation. I just don’t know how to get there @Schach21

Comment: What is your math level? To solve that question you can simply use the formula $b=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}y$ assuming the original equation is written as $y=Ab$ in matrix notation. You can also find the row space and null space using the Grand-Schmidt orthonormalization algorithm and solve for your particular $y$. This is a very common question, I'd suggest you do some googling and find a way that you feel comfortable with.

Comment: can you please just show me how i’d even get a=5. i’ve never seen that formula before @Schach21

Answer (score 1):

The augmented matrix of the system is

$\begin{bmatrix} 3 && -9 && 2 && -1 && 4 \\ 1 && - 3 && 1 && 2 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $

Exchanging the two rows,

$\begin{bmatrix}  1 && - 3 && 1 && 2 && -1 \\3 && -9 && 2 && -1 && 4 \end{bmatrix} $

Adding $(-3) R_1 $ to $ R_2$

$\begin{bmatrix}  1 && - 3 && 1 && 2 && -1 \\0 && 0 && -1 && -7 && 7 \end{bmatrix} $

Finally, multiplying $R_2$ by $(-1)$

$\begin{bmatrix}  1 && - 3 && 1 && 2 && -1 \\0 && 0 && 1 && 7 && -7 \end{bmatrix} $

Adding $-R_2 $ to $R_1$, we get,

$\begin{bmatrix}  1 && - 3 && 0 && -5 && 6 \\0 && 0 && 1 && 7 && -7 \end{bmatrix} $

This matrix is in reduced row echelon form, mark the leading $1's$ columns, and take the rest of the column variables (not the last column) as arbitrary variables, i.e.

$ x_2 = t $

$ x_4 = s $

where $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$

Then it follows by reading the two equations that

$x_1 = 6 + 3 x_2 + 5 x_4 = 6 + 3 t + 5 s  $

$x_3 = -7 - 7 x_4 = -7 - 7 s $

In vector form, this is,

$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (6, 0, -7, 0) + t (3, 1, 0, 0) + s (5, 0, -7, 1) $

and this expresses the solutions in terms of a constant vector $(6,0,-7,0)$ and two spanning vectors $(3, 1, 0, 0)$ and $(5, 0, -7,1)$.

Comment: you made a mistake in the 3rd matrix: 4-(-3) is 7, not8, thanks anyway!!!

Comment: so I won’t be able to solve a,b,c or d as variables right? I.e. a=2, b=3, etc? @Hosam Hajjir

Comment: Yes, you can. Your solutions are of the form: $a=7+3t+5s,b=t,c=-8-7s,d=s$ where $t,s$ are any numbers. Hence one solution would be: $a=7+3(0)+5(-1)=2,b=0,c=-1,d=-1$.

Comment: Thanks @Ghost, I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: The 7 next to the -5 in the last matrix should be a 6 as well :) @Hosan Hajjir

Comment: Oops.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I've corrected that as well.